# iPad suitable for 18X7 environment?

Tags: ipad

An industrial application needs a barcode scanning kiosk and upload scans 18 hours a day,7 days a week.  Users are not expected to touch the display, however, the display will be on broadcasting instructions and providing feedback that scans are successful.

Has the iPad been tested or used in 18X7 duty cycles or similar high duty cycles?

Comment: What does the user manual say about use?

Comment: @SolarMike The one at https://help.apple.com/ipad/11/ ? Probably nothing

Comment: @SolarMike  I believe your question is trying to make a point, however, can you clarify?

Comment: Most things are sold with a « guide » about the expected or normal use - just wondered if you had looked at that before asking...

Answer (score 3):

Our iPads in factory settings are less expensive, faster to interact with and break less than all the other hardware we deploy. This includes corrosive atmosphere environments, metallic dust and all manner of things that tend to short out gear. Even if they failed at a rate twice of computers, they’re still cheaper to replace than other options we could use for our application.

The resale value of lightly used iPads is so high I’d start a pilot program immediately if you’re on the fence.

Comment: Excellent comments.   Do you scan items or is it used as a terminal by workers? Are there any limitations that have been found (i.e. root access, etc.)?

Comment: I use iPads in a barcode scanning situation (though not 18/7). There is a guided access mode that you can use to lock users out of using the home button to go to another app. I'm not sure if it is perfectly secure, but it works for us as well as the PIN we use to lock them. Once we locked them that way the only issues we have had so far have been with the barcode scanning app. (and some bluetooth printers we connected, but that's irrelevant :D)

Comment: @dwightk  I think (please to correct if need be) that the camera in your iPad is scanning barcodes.

Comment: yep... barcodes on keyrings like loyalty clubs have. edit: Oh, I see what you are asking: Yes, it is the camera on the ipad.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen many iPads used for kiosks in retail stores around Ireland where I live. These never seem to be turned off and are always working when I see them.

But, if you're looking for something a little more substantial:

> http://edition.cnn.com/2011/TECH/innovation/02/28/FAA.approves.iPads/index.html
>
> The Federal Aviation Administration is allowing charter company Executive Jet Management to use Apple's tablet as an approved alternative to paper charts.

If it's good enough to use in aviation, I'd expect it to be good enough for most things. Theres some more detail on [cockpit iPads on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockpit_iPads).

Comment: It would interesting to understand what requirements or testing the FAA would approve (or more importantly disqualify) an electronic device.  In my aviation experience, concerns with electronics in cockpit are centered around interference with other electronic systems.